# Windows Phone 7: All I get is System.MethodAccessException

Tags: windows-phone-7

This is my first time to develop apps in Windows Phone 7 and I was not that welcome. LOL.

Anyways, my problem is this MethodAccessException and am not sure why it keeps throwing me that exception.

Here's what I was trying to do.

1. **Getting Application StartUp Path by**:
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase
   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName
   API:
   [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern int GetModuleFileName(IntPtr hModule, StringBuilder lpFilename, int nSize);
2. **Try to just enumerate some files**
   int c = Directory.GetFiles(@"\").Length;
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("total files: " + c);

and am not sure what else since I just started coding. I have a big app in mind, and it will cover Registry IO, File IOs, and Database. But if this MethodAccessException keeps blocking my way, I'd rather be dead.

Am using Windows Phone 7.0
6176.WM7 RC1Escrow(buildlab).20100406 1457

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Reflection or P/Invokes in Phone 7.

For File I/O you should be using IsolatedStorageFile for dealing with files.  [See this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Isolated_Storage_Demo.aspx) (among many on the web).

There is no Registry access (maybe explaining why you think you need it can lead us to providing alternatives).

For Database access, there are lots of options.  Depends on where you want the database (local/remote/cloud), what engine you want, ORM preferences, etc.

Comment: Right. I have read this IsolatedStorage stuff. But it's my first time so I was exploring some other ways. So when dealing with FileIOs, IsolatedStorage would be the best answer?

Comment: ok. I immediately commented on your answer. Anyway, in registry access, I have seen http://advancedexplorerwp7.codeplex.com does it. In my to-make-app lists, one of it are WP7 customization, so It does really need an Registry access and of course exploring it first is a must before doing anything.