# method access exception in wp7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, methodaccessexception

I am working on WP project i need to get the images from local folder, when I use Directory.GetFiles() method i get 'System.MethodAccessException' but it works fine on a device.
Can anybody please explain me the reason?

Regards,
Sonya

Comment: Can you check the following answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7612698/1565574

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`IsolatedStorage.GetFileNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02ys433%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of `Directory.GetFiles`.